# John Resig Micro templating bug

Tags: javascript, regex, client-side-templating, templating-engine

So I am aiming to use [John Resig's templating engine](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating).

I need to pass the function a variable containing the "template". However, the problem is that I need to pass something like:

```
<script>
console.log("Double quotes");
</script>
<script>
console.log('single');
</script>
<iframe src="http://example.com/?<%=SOME_VARIABLE%>" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<div>I think I'm going to break</div>
<% for ( var i = 0; i < users.length; i++ ) { %>
<li><a href="<%=users[i]%>"><%=users[i]%></a></li>
<% } %>
<iframe src='http://example.com/?<%=SOME_VARIABLE%>' frameborder="0"></iframe>
<div>I think I"m going to break</div>
<% for ( var i = 0; i < users.length; i++ ) { %>
<li><a href='<%=users[i]%>'><%=users[i]%></a></li>
<% } %>
```

The thing that seems to break is:

```
<script>
console.log('single');
</script>
```

With this bit of code being passed through the Regex it fails. It is important that I am able to pass any of the above code and have it not break. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I came across this article which has a fix for this (also changes the <% %> to <# #> FYI

```
str.replace(/[\r\t\n]/g, " ")
               .replace(/'(?=[^#]*#>)/g, "\t")
               .split("'").join("\\'")
               .split("\t").join("'")
               .replace(/<#=(.+?)#>/g, "',$1,'")
               .split("<#").join("');")
               .split("#>").join("p.push('")
               + "');}return p.join('');";
```

http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2008/Oct/13/Client-Templating-with-jQuery